# Android keystore signature problem

Tags: java, android, keytool

Ok, so I am trying to work with the facebook API, but having no luck with this keystore. I can get it to generate and give my a signature, but the app keeps telling me invalid_key. I was reading around and some people were saying that you have to use linux to get a good signature, which I find hard to believe. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to get the key from your keystore and put it on the facebook website.

Follow the guide here...

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android

Basically you need to extract the key from your keystore. The following command extracts the key `androiddebugkey` from a keystore called `debug.keystore` (both of these are auto created by Eclipse). The password for `androiddebugkeystore` is `android`.

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore 
| openssl sha1 -binary
| openssl base64
```

Once you have the number from that, you put it in the Key hash field on your Facebook app's page.. [image: Facebook App page]

The key follows the same format seen in the image.

Comment: Ive done that, got a code, but the signature doesnt work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What signature are you getting? what does it look like?

Comment: I was getting a correct signature, but for some reason or another it turns out it wouldnt work if I had the official Facebook app installed on my phone.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your supplying exactly what they ask for. If they ask for a `MD5` key, the `SHA1` key won't work, and vice versa. If you want a `MD5` key and you are only getting a `SHA1` key, then try installing the older 1.6 version of the Java Development Kit (JDK).

The new one (1.7) only gives a `SHA1` key. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am using JDK 1.7 and had the same issue.  by putting a -v into your keytool command it will give you the MD5, SHA1, and SHA256 fingerprints

$ keytool -v -list -alias androiddebugkey...etc.  Then grab the MD5 for use with Google or Facebook.

Found this answer here: http://mirnauman.wordpress.com/2012/01/26/how-to-get-google-maps-api-key-for-android-issues-and-errors-solved/